# How to make ScrollView for size of content?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to make ScrollView for size of content?

Comment: you are using _check for transmission and comparing check1 in second check with case
.write if(_check == 1){}

Comment: what added. Is that working?

Comment: ViewController *ViewController  dont make this.. Instead make this
ViewController *viewController

Comment: check the value first what are you getting in index path

Comment: if(_check == 0) - image shows
if(_check == 1) - image not shows

Comment: check if u have that corresponding image in your bundle 2.png. Also check the value of indexpath when u tap second cell;

Comment: How to check the value of indexpath?

Comment: just print it or if you are using a debugger just po it in console

Comment: Show what you have done so far. And do not edit completely the question. Answers then do not correlate with your question. Create new one,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by many ways

1. You can make a object in Table view controller and similar object in View Controller and while pushing or presenting the view controller from tableview controller you can pass the object

Examples

```
make an objA in TableViewController
make an similar objA ViewController
```

Now when pushing and presenting.. Just pass

```
viewControllerObj.objA = objA
```

and access

2. Second way is storing object in NSUserDefault in TableViewController and getting in view controller.
3. By adding in Core Data or Sqlite and fetching
4. By adding in plist and fetching
5. By making a singleton model class and initiating values in TableVC and accessing it in VC